Is there a dimensional multiplication operation?
When expressing numbers with any unit, we know this. We can multiply and divide numbers with different types of units, but we cannot add or compare them.
From Terry Tao's 2012 blog post "A mathematical formalisation of dimensional analysis" (via terrytao.wordpress.com) (paragraph 6):

There is however one important limitation to the ability to manipulate “dimensionful” quantities as if they were numbers: one is not supposed to add, subtract, or compare two physical quantities if they have different dimensions, although it is acceptable to multiply or divide two such quantities. For instance, if ${m}$ is a mass (having the units ${M}$) and ${v}$ is a speed (having the units ${LT^{-1}}$), then it is physically “legitimate” to form an expression such as ${\frac{1}{2} mv^2}$, but not an expression such as ${m+v}$ or ${m-v}$; in a similar spirit, statements such as ${m=v}$ or ${m\geq v}$ are physically meaningless.

While expressing numbers with objects, if we assign units to objects, we can analyze the following operations.

As you can see above, we cannot collect 1 apple and 1 pear. Now I want to mention this: When performing operations on integers, considering them as vectors in one dimension and performing operations works perfectly. If we consider integers in one dimension, multiplying two numbers that do not have any units is actually repetitive addition. Or multiplying a number with a unit in a dimension by a number without a unit is also repetitive addition. However, while studying geometry, I noticed something. It is meaningless to multiply numbers with different units in one dimension.
Also from Tao's post (paragraph 10):

As mentioned before, it is then geometrically natural to multiply two lengths to form an area, by taking a rectangle whose line segments have the stated lengths, and using the area of that rectangle as a product. This geometric picture works well for units such as length and volume that have a spatial geometric interpretation, but it is less clear how to apply it for more general units. For instance, it does not seem geometrically natural (or, for that matter, conceptually helpful) to envision the equation ${E=mc^2}$ as the assertion that the energy ${E}$ is the volume of a rectangular box whose height is the mass ${m}$ and whose length and width is given by the speed of light ${c}$.


We can multiply or divide numbers that have a unit. However, multiplying $4m$ length by $4m$ length in one dimension is meaningless. But when calculating the area of ​​a square, we can multiply the length of $4m$ in two different dimensions $(4m\cdot 4m=16m^{2})$.
My question:

We can approach numbers in many different ways. They can act as one-dimensional vectors in relation to objects (for example, apples, pears), or in the number direction. We can even manipulate units like numbers. So, does dimensional multiplication really exist ?


The "$E=mc^2$" equation is one of the most misunderstood equations in physics. Not the formula itself , but its interpretation that mass and energy are equivalent which is plain wrong.

@Peter That part is quoted from the world-famous mathematician Terrytao.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Your post is long, but I think it amounts to "I can multiply two lengths in $2$ dimensions but not $1$ dimension, so is it valid?" To which I need to ask a question to clarify: what do you mean by multiplying in $n$ dimensions? If you just mean the answer is $2$-dimensional, it's like you're asking if it makes sense to multiply $7$ by $9$ even though it gives a $2$-digit answer. But maybe you meant something else.

Did you learn about tensor products?

@MoisheKohan No, unfortunately I did not learn tensor products.

Too bad, since Tao explains in his blog how to make sense of the dimensional analysis using tensors.

From everyday experience, it is much more natural to have 1 basket + 1 apple + 1 pear than 1 apple$\cdot$pear$\cdot$basket. I wouldn't even know what that means. The numbers measured in a lab always end up being dimensionless ratios, and units are bookkeeping tools while calculating, which, while useful, are often omitted (cf natural units). That is not to say that the ways they can be made rigorous mathematically aren't interesting.

@tobi_s: 1 basket + 1 apple + 1 pear is more like a disjoint union, which is related to the notion of coproduct.

@tobi_s "1 basket + 1 apple + 1 pear" is syntax abuse: this is not addition, you're implicitly placing stuff into baskets. In particular, this doesn't seem to be associative, which I would consider an essential property of addition: "(1 basket + 1 apple + 1 apple) + (1 pear + 1 basket)" and "(1 basket + 1 apple) + (1 apple + 1 pear + 1 basket)" give different results. What you're actually doing here is more like, basket is a function that takes lists (or, multisets) of fruit as input.

@leftaroundabout my aim was to point out that picturing the addition of two objects as something happening in the real world doesn't really correspond to mathematical operations with units. Just like multiplication of units doesn't really correspond to anything within our geometric intuition of the 3D world. The basket just made for a nicer image. It's interesting how you immediately ascribed a lot of meaning to it.

What is the reason for closing this question, which has received many upvotes and answers? The question is very clear. If you are not going to open the question, let me delete my question. Because I'm really bored.

The answer is yes, and it's called tensor product.
For beginner, we can think about the tensor product of two vectors $v$ and $w$, which not necessary have the same dimension, to be a matrix $v\otimes w=(v_iw_j)_{i,j}$.
Tensor is something that's also used in physics, for example the stress tensor. This more complicated then you expect for but it is kind of a product.
As for $4m\times 4m=16m^2$, roughly speaking we are talking about the determinant of a matrix. If we have vectors $v=(4,0)$ and $w=(0,4)$ in the same space, the length are $|v|=|w|=4$ and their tensor product is $\begin{pmatrix}4&0\\0&4\end{pmatrix}$ which has determinant $16$.

Why is the first $4m$ term represented differently than the second one?

@ipsec I don't think I understand your question. v and w are both vectors, and 4m are their "length".

Put another way, why is $4m \times 4m$ represented by these two vectors in particular? Why not $(4,0) \otimes (4,0)$, for example?

@ipsec If you ask for $(4,0)\otimes(4,0)$ you are looking for a parallelogram span by $(4,0)$ and $(4,0)$, which has area 0, but not 16.

In my opinion the tensor product is not the answer to the original question (which operation can express multiplication with units) if I already have to know the result to determine which product I have to use.

@ipsec There are two kind of products of units, the $m^2$ and the $m\cdot s$ are different in some sense. When you think about $m\cdot s$ you have to make the "length object" and "time object" to be "orthonogal". But for $m^2$ you allow the two objects to be skew or even colinear. Also the unit here is a norm of a vector and not describing the whole thing. Honestly I don't think I understand your question well in the comment.

Since there are only seven fundamental units in physics, we may establish dimensional analysis as following:
Let $U$ be a (finitely generated) free abelian group (with multiplication notation instead of addition), then any (physical) quantity is just an element from the group algebra $\mathbb R[U]$ (if necessary $\mathbb C[U]$).
In particular, we're allowed to form $1\text{ apple}+1\text{ pear}$ in your picture. Or in real physics $1\text{ meter} + 2 \text{ second} + 3 \text{ kilogram}$, but we cannot add the numbers $1, 2, 3$ together. We also have no problem with $2\text{ meter/second} = 2 \text{ meter}\cdot \text{second}^{-1}$ since division is allowed in $U$.
This looks more natural to me than to introduce the dual spaces and tensor product. Since $(10s)(3s^{-1})=30$ is natural, while $(10s)\otimes 3(s^{-1})$ is not readily $30$ before the contraction. (I haven't read Tao's post in details, maybe there are good reasons to prefer tensor product.)

Please clarify what you mean "in real physics we're allowed to form $1m + 2s + 3kg$", that part makes absolutely no sense to me.

For example, a typical thermodynamic system has many quantities: Mass, temperature, pressure, entropy, etc. These may be compactly written as a formal sum. Of course this doesn't add any benefit in practice, but this is conceptually better in the sense that it's better than to form the vector, as the components would have different units and vectors are meant to be coordinate-free.

I think that you might be confusing two quite different uses of the word "dimension".
The "dimension" used in vector spaces is about linear independence and not units of measure.  In pure mathematics, we rarely consider units of measure.  When vector spaces are used in physics, the different "dimensions" would typically (always?) have the same units of measure e.g. $x$, $y$, and $z$ all in metres.  It would, in some cases at least, be appropriate to add an $x$ value to a $y$ value even though they are different "dimensions" e.g. calculating the perimeter of a rectangle.
However, physics also uses "dimension" in a very different sense of units of measure.  In this sense, it is not appropriate to add values in different dimensions, e.g. the mass of a sample in $kg$ and its length in $m$.
So, the same word but with two different uses.  Try to figure out which is being used in each case.  It is a shame that this has occurred but it occurs in other places as well.  Another example is "field".  Its use in pure mathematics and physics is also quite different.  For "field", I know that some other languages (e.g. French and German) use quite different words.  I don't know whether this applies to "dimension".

If you read the linked Tao's article, you will find out (he is making sense of the notion of inits of measure and dimensional analysis used by physicists).

In some instances, we can add or subtract with dimensions. The dimensions must correspond to commensurate pbysical quantities. In practical problems this comes up in temperature conversions.
Problem: convert s spe ified dee point aim of -10°C to Fahrenheit.
Solution:
$-10°\text{C}×\dfrac{1.8°\text{F}}{°\text{C}}\color{blue}{+(32°\text{F}-0°\text{C})}$
$=14°\text{F}.$
The multiplicative factor is sufficuent to convert the temperature increments from Celsius to Fahrenheit, but we must add an offset term that identifies $32°\text{F}$ with $0°\text{C}$. Note that if we apply the multiplicative factor first,the offset has to match with zero of the input unit to be consistent with $0×$(multiplicative factor)$=0$.
